# Removing a core order status

Tags: php, woocommerce, status

I’m trying to remove 3 order statuses from woocommerce: wc-pending, wc-refunded and wc-failed.

I tried to remove them from `/wc-order-functions.php`, but when I did, I could not longer place an order. Instead an error 400 is returned, which means it cannot insert the order into the database.

Does anyone have a solution for this? How can order statuses be removed or disabled?

Comment: Do you want to hide the orders with these statuses? or you want to remove them completely? You know there is a strong requirement basis on what they have put them in the core. That means you should not try to remove them.

Comment: No, i do not want to remove them. i want to don't appear in the backend, edit order section...I am trying to play with css and visibility element but it disapears the whole  " edit order" dropdown section.

Comment: May be I can help you out, but first of all please specify exactly which elements and where you want to make the changes. Woocommerce has a lot of filters and actions

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It seems like you are making a lot of extra work for very little gain. How will you know what the status of the order is?

Comment: It's for a pizza delivery service site , so the client needs the just the : "On hold", "Deleted", "Processing" , "Complete".For example i don't need the awaiting payment to appear in the backend site ..It  conflicts the client..So because i can't delete this i'm thinking if there is a way to hide with css.The field i want to hide is the dropdaown menu when you click "Edit Order".

Answer (score 0):

Please check FAQ in woo extension here :
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-order-status-manager/

> Q: Why can’t I delete core order statuses like I can with custom statuses?
>
> A: All core order statuses, even those that you may not typically use in your workflow, are used by plugins. As these plugins expect core order statuses to be present, we cannot remove them so that we don’t break the plugins, like payment gateways, that depend on them.
>
> You can edit the names for these statuses if desired, but cannot delete these statuses or change the slugs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion...Is there any sollution at least to remove or hide them from the list inside the order page without delete the functionality and don't break the core of woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but figured I'd answer it for you!
To simply hide the selection options, use this css:

```
select option[value="wc-pending"], 
select option[value="wc-refunded"], 
select option[value="wc-failed"] 
{
   display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to remove core order statuses for the very good reasons explained by @SweetCoder , however what you can do is hide them. Your function will look something like this:

```
function hide_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {

    // Hide core statuses
    unset( $order_statuses['wc-refunded'] );
    unset( $order_statuses['wc-failed'] );
    unset( $order_statuses['wc-on-hold'] );
    unset( $order_statuses['wc-cancelled'] );
    unset( $order_statuses['wc-pending'] );
    unset( $order_statuses['wc-processing'] );
    unset( $order_statuses['wc-completed'] );

    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'hide_wc_order_statuses' );
```